# Como exibir todos os resultados de um SELECT em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Já fiz esse código todo sozinho, porém estou com dificuldades para exibir todos os resultados um abaixo do outro.

```
    <?php include 'conexao.php'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GMB Mineração e Comércio LTDA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <h1>Clientes</h1>
        <fieldset class="row2">
          <legend><font color="white">-</font></legend>
            <p>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * from clientes";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    $fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                    $final = $fetch[0];
                ?>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Assim:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * from clientes";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<p>". $fetch[0] . " - " . $fetch[1] . " - " . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

Tem uma série de outras maneiras de fazer isto. Depende da necessidade específica.

Você poderia fazer algo assim (mais recomendado (mas é só um exemplo, não sei como está sua estrutura):

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT cnpj, nome from clientes";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<p>". $fetch[0] . " - " . $fetch[1] . " - " . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

Desta forma você traz apenas os campos que você vai usar. Mas se for colocar todos os campos da tabela mesmo, pode fazer isto:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<p>";
        foreach ($fetch as $value) {
            echo $value . " - ";
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/ViewSelect.php).

Ainda dá para fazer de um jeito melhor. Mas acho que a ideia é só te dar a ideia básica, o ideal é que montasse isto usando uma `<table>` ou uma forma mais estruturada de organizar estes dados. Mas acho que você deve dar um passo de cada vez.

O ideal também seria você usar o [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) que é uma API mais moderna e recomendada.

Comment: Fica exibindo erros, a resposta do rray funcionou porém só está exibindo o ID do primeiro e segundo resultados.

Comment: Ah, sim, agora entendi, mas eu tenho mesmo que escrever cada resultado? Por exemplo, essa tabela tem cerca de 40 colunas :S

Comment: Eu editei para ficar mais fácil de encaixar no que você precisa. Não melhoro porque não sei exatamente o resultado que você quer obter e nem a estrutura de sua tabela. Note que estou te mostrando fazer algo bem básico. A forma que você está fazendo não é o ideal, mas ela funciona. Você pega o que você deseja. Você não tem que colocar o que você não quer que apareça. Além disto, se quiser que apareça tudo , pode colocar um outro *loop*, interno para automatizar, vou ver se melhor agora que você está passando novas informações.

Comment: Mas procure sempre colocar o máximo de informações possível do que você deseja na própria pergunta, mesmo que tenha que editá-la.

Answer (score 3):

O correto é usar MySQLi, não MySQL.

```
<?php
$MySQLi = new MySQLi( 'servidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco' );
$query = "SELECT * from clientes";
$result = $MySQLi->query($query);
while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p>";
    foreach ($fetch as $field => $value) {
        echo $field . ' => ' . $value . ' | ';
    }
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. É preferível usar MySQLi, como mostrei acima ou PDO, que é até mais vantajoso. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

Adicione um while no `mysql_fetch_*` dessa forma o PHP avalia se a função retorna true ou false, caso positivo é feita atribuição. Para exibir as 40 colunas de forma 'automatica' crie um for.

```
$str = '';                      
while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   for($i=0; $i<40; $i++){
      $str .= $linha[$i] .' - ';
   }
}
echo $str . '<br>';
```

As funções mysql_* já estão defasadas a bastante tempo, veja o porque em: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91), o recomendado é utilizar o mysqli ou PDO.

Comment: Eu apago essa linha?  $final = $fetch[0];

Comment: Se for apenas exibir os valores pode chamar direto não precisa de uma variável, se for guardar todos os itens para usar depois, crie um array.

Comment: Para exibir, todos os campos, é so mudar a chave do array: 
`echo $linha[0] .' - '. $linha[1] .' - '. $linha[2];`. No seu banco existe mais de duas linhas?

Comment: Entendi. No caso está exibindo o ID do primeiro e do segundo resultado. Como faço para exibir todos os dados ao invez de um a um?

Comment: São cerca de 40 colunas nessa tabela :S